# How can I read a bytearray from an HttpResponse?

Tags: android

I'm making an http connection using following code:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
```

I want to read a bytearray from the response object.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 6):

You can read the byte array directly with the method: **EntityUtils.toByteArray**

Example

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet get = new HttpGet("localhost:8080/myurl");
HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
byte[] content = EntityUtils.toByteArray(response.getEntity());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
String content = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
byte[] bytes = content.getBytes("UTF8");
```

You can replace the character encoding with one appropriate for the response.

Comment: Highly dangerous advice. You can get corrupted bytes not matching with what returns server in response originally. First data decoded to Unicode string (probably with errors/corruptions) and then encoded to UTF-8 which can be not an encoding used in original response

Answer (score 0):

I did something very similar to this, but it was a while ago.

Looking at my source code I used

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
String url = "http://192.168.1.69:8888/sdroidmarshal";
HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
String proto = client.execute(getRequest, responseHandler);
```

I'm pretty certain that the ResponseHandler is the key to this. My get request simply returned something I needed as a string, which was quite simple.

In the case of a bytearray you'll probably want to use an InputStream like so

```
ResponseHandler<InputStream> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
InputStream in = client.execute(getRequest, responseHandler);
```

After which just handle the InputStream as normal.

A bit of googling suggested you may also need to use HttpResponseHandler() rather than BasicResponseHandler() as in my example, I'd fiddle.

The full source code of my work is [here](https://github.com/goldx/ShopDroid/blob/master/src/griffib/shopdroid/comms/SDroidClient.java), it might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin Way**

run this on async task on background thread otherwise it will through the error that network task is running on main thread

```
doAsync {
            val client: HttpClient = DefaultHttpClient()
            val get = HttpPost("*your url*")
            get.setHeader("Authorization","Bearer "+Utils.token)
            val response: HttpResponse = client.execute(get)
            val content = EntityUtils.toByteArray(response.getEntity())

            onComplete {
                createPdf(content)
            }
        }
```